# Orika ClassCastException in Eclipse on redeploy

Tags: eclipse, liferay-7, liferay-ide, orika

I am using orika-core-1.5.4.jar in my Liferay 7.3.5 CE GA6 Portlet in order to map some classes. Everything goes well if I test it in a main method or if it is the first time when the portlet is deployed, but goes awry if I redeploy it - eg. when I make some changes and then deploy them. The error is the following:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_MedicForm_FormDTO_Mapper850365342121300$0 cannot be cast to ma.glasnost.orika.impl.GeneratedObjectBase
```

From what I have read ([here](https://liguoliang.com/default/2019/07/16/orika-classcastexception-with-spring-boot-devtools.html) is an interesting article and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324944/orika-classcastexception-in-spring-boot-webapp) stack article), this is because the first time, the class  was generated with a AppClassLoader and the second time with RestartClassLoader - the articles refers to Spring applications. But I am not clear how to manage this. Now, I have to restart the server each time in order to avoid this.

Any ideas would help, thanks !

Comment: If your code or orika library has any static variable you can have problem because the classloader of the OSGI modules are different in each module startup, so if you store a static reference, after the module restart, that class will belong to the old classloader, causing a ClassCastException in case you use it.
So review your code and avoid using static variable and also review the orika library to double check if it is osgi-friendly.

Comment: @jorgediaz-lr I'll give it a try and come back with updates. Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to respond to this change - I made it non static and also made it at method scope (not class scope), but still returns the same exception on restart.